# Intent is not started through scanner when using emdk profile manager

Tags: android, barcode-scanner, motorola-emdk

I followed [this](http://techdocs.zebra.com/emdk-for-android/4-0/tutorial/tutdatacaptureprofilePt2/) tutorial to scan a bar code and display in the text view everything works fine but the scanned bar code is not displayed in the text view.As from the below you can see the handledata is never called when i scan the code through TC70 zebra device.As i expected the below code to create a new intent and call the handledata from new Intent method.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
      <uses-permission android:name="com.symbol.emdk.permission.EMDK"/>

   <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <uses-library android:name="com.symbol.emdk"/>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.lisec.emdktest.intentsample.RECVR"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

MainActivity.java

```
    package com.lisec.emdktest.intentsample;

    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import com.symbol.emdk.EMDKManager;
    import com.symbol.emdk.EMDKResults;
    import com.symbol.emdk.ProfileManager;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements                         EMDKManager.EMDKListener {

//Assign the profile name used in EMDKConfig.xml
private String profileName = "NewDataCapture";

//Declare a variable to store ProfileManager object
private ProfileManager mProfileManager = null;

//Declare a variable to store EMDKManager object
private EMDKManager emdkManager = null;

private TextView textViewBarcode = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //The EMDKManager object will be created and returned in the callback.
    EMDKResults results = EMDKManager.getEMDKManager(getApplicationContext(), this);

    //Check the return status of getEMDKManager
    if(results.statusCode == EMDKResults.STATUS_CODE.FAILURE)
    {
        //Failed to create EMDKManager object

    }

    textViewBarcode = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewBarcode);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    handleDecodeData(i);
}

            //This function is responsible for getting 
            the data from the                                 
            intent
            private void handleDecodeData(Intent i)
            {
            //Check the intent action is for us
            if (i.getAction().contentEquals
            ("com.lisec.emdktest.intentsample.RECVR") ) {
            String source =                 
            i.getStringExtra
            ("com.motorolasolutions.emdk.datawedge.source");

            //Check if the data has come from the Barcode scanner
        if(source.equalsIgnoreCase("scanner"))
        {
            //Get the data from the intent
    String data =                         
    i.getStringExtra
    ("com.motorolasolutions.emdk.datawedge.data_string");

    //Check that we have received data
            if(data != null && data.length() > 0)
            {
                textViewBarcode.setText("Data = " + data);
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent i) {
    handleDecodeData(i);

}

@Override
public void onOpened(EMDKManager emdkManager) {
    this.emdkManager = emdkManager;
    //Get the ProfileManager object to process the profiles
    mProfileManager = (ProfileManager)         
    emdkManager.getInstance
    (EMDKManager.FEATURE_TYPE.PROFILE);
    if(mProfileManager != null)
    {
        try{

            String[] modifyData = new String[1];
            //Call processPrfoile with profile name
            and SET flag to create                 
            the profile. 
            The modifyData can be null.

            EMDKResults results = mProfileManager.
            processProfile(profileName, 
            ProfileManager.PROFILE_FLAG.SET, modifyData);
            if(results.statusCode == EMDKResults.STATUS_CODE.FAILURE)
            {
                //Failed to set profile
            }
        }catch (Exception ex){
            // Handle any exception
        }


    }
}

@Override
public void onClosed() {

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    //Clean up the objects created by EMDK manager
    emdkManager.release();
  }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing the different ways to retrieve scanned data. Intents are only sent from the DataWedge service (http://techdocs.zebra.com/datawedge/6-0/guide/about/) but you are also initialising the EMDK library (http://techdocs.zebra.com/emdk-for-android/6-0/guide/gettingstarted/). EMDK returns its data via callback.

If you choose the DataWedge route, I have an application which listens for DataWedge intents that might help: https://github.com/darryncampbell/DataWedge-API-Exerciser

If you choose the EMDK route, there are samples on Zebra's own site: http://techdocs.zebra.com/emdk-for-android/6-0/samples/barcode/

If you use the EMDK in your application it will automatically take priority over DataWedge so your application would never receive data via intents unless you delete the EMDK code.

Comment: Thanks @DarrynCampbell that was very helpful , can you provide me a suggestion before starting development on which to go for EMDK or Data Wedge I will say my Application is just normal scanning app where i will use the scanned bar code to send to server to fetch and dsiplay some information as html.I am developing this using YC70 zebra device.

Comment: If you need to modify the behaviour of the scanner at runtime or need high frequency scanning then I would recommend the EMDK.  If you are just looking for ease of development and scanning at a maximum rate of about once a second then DataWedge will work for you.  The reason I focus on scan rate is because Intents (or keystrokes) take some finite time to be delivered.

Comment: I am trying to scan the barcode and intent after scanning for the TC26BK zebra device but it's not working Could you please suggest a sample demo because my sample apk is not even installed on the device. - @DarrynCampbell

Comment: @Dhara-Patel I would recommend my unofficial getting started guide at https://medium.com/@darryncampbell_83863/getting-started-with-datawedge-on-zebra-devices-9af2cdd1110c and accompanying apps on github https://github.com/darryncampbell/DataWedge-GettingStarted-Samples